# i18n react return [object object]

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next

I have an object like this one :

```
{
 comment: "autogenerated"
 createdDate: "2021-09-21T14:32:47"
 id: 7831
 lastModifiedDate: "2021-09-21T14:32:47"
 media: "LETTER"
}
```

Knowing that `media` can return different values like: "LETTER", "PHONE" "EMAIL".

I would like my translation to change depending on the value returned by `media`

```
const renderMedia = (media: string) => {
   return (
    <>
      {t(`press.text`, {
        media: presentMedia(media),
      })}
    </>
   );
 };
```

The `presentMedia()` function returns a translation based on the value returned by `media`

```
 const presentMedia = (media: string) => {
      switch (media) {
       case 'PHONE':
        return <span>t('press.media.phone')</span>;

       case 'LETTER':
         return <span>{t('press.media.letter')}</span>;

       case 'EMAIL':
           return <span>t('press.media.email')</span>;
      }
     };
```

the i18n file :

```
 "press": {
   "text": "files {{media}}",
   "media": {
     "phone": " by phone",
     "letter": "bu letter",
     "email": "bu email"
   },
```

on the other hand the function presentMedia return `[object, Object]` while I thought to recover the translation present in the `switch`

if I replace `<span>{t('press.media.letter')}</span>` it with a simple string `<span>test</span>` it is displayed

is there a problem with using i18n React in a function ?

There may be another solution that would give me the same result?

Comment: Let me know if you try the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have one CodeSanbox with the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-allen-oujoc?file=/src/App.js

The error is: `presetMedia` is returning a `[object Object]` because you're returning also the `<span>`. So, it's a React Node (or [objectObject])

I'd recommend change:

```js
 const presentMedia = (media: string) => {
      switch (media) {
       case 'PHONE':
        return <span>{t('press.media.phone')}</span>;

       case 'LETTER':
         return <span>{t('press.media.letter')}</span>;

       case 'EMAIL':
           return <span>{t('press.media.email')}</span>;
      }
     };
```

to this:

```js
const presentMedia = (media: string) => {
  switch (media) {
    case 'PHONE':
      return t('press.media.phone');

    case 'LETTER':
      return t('press.media.letter');

    case 'EMAIL':
      return t('press.media.email');
  }
};
```

Finally, If it works, I'd suggest change to this:

```js
const presentMedia = (media: string) => t(`press.media.${media.toLowerCase()`);
```

Answer (score 0):

These cases are not the same, 2 of them lack `{}`. Fix them to see if the problem is solved. If not please provide us with the code for `t`.

```
       case 'PHONE':
        return <span>t('press.media.phone')</span>;

       case 'LETTER':
         return <span>{t('press.media.letter')}</span>;

       case 'EMAIL':
           return <span>t('press.media.email')</span>;
```